# Enable HTTPS for Akka-Discovery Endpoints while forming akka-cluster in kubernetes environment

Tags: akka, akka-http, akka-cluster

I need to setup up an Akka-Cluster (using Akka Classic) in Kubernetes using DNS-resolver. I've created a headless-service which is able to resolve address for various pods of my Akka application.
After DNS resolving, I'm able to get addresses for various pods. Now my Akka-Management runs over Https,

So while one pod tries connecting to management endpoints of various other pods, It needs to use "HTTPS" instead of "HTTP" but Akka by default uses "http". Is there a way to modify this behavior in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is: to enable HTTPS, you have to instantiate your server by providing an `HttpsConnectionContext` object to it.

You should probably do something like:

```java
Http.get(system).newServerAt("localhost", 8080)
    .enableHttps(createHttpsContext(system))
    .bind(app.createRoute());
```

The previous example is taken from the [official documentation](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/server-side/server-https-support.html), which also shows how the `createHttpsContext(system)` method works.

Comment: My question is more on client behavior of akka-cluster-bootstrap. Server can be started on https, but how to modify the client of akka cluster bootstrap to use https